# How to find a match on all tags with specific content?

Tags: regex

i have follow xml:

```
<tag>
    ...
</tag>
<tag>
    ...
    content
    ...
</tag>
<tag>
    ...
    content
    ...
</tag>
```

I have to match only tags with `content`

At first I tried this regex:

```
<tag>.*?content.*?<\/tag>
```

but in case there is a tag that not have `content` captures too much...

then, I am tryed to recognize it using the following regular expression with negative lookahead:

```
<tag>.*?(?!<\/tag>).*?content.*?<\/tag>
```

but it dosn't work.

link to online regex debugger: https://regex101.com/r/ULZVO5/10

Comment: Why are you parsing xml with regexes? Use an xml parser instead.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting comment. Тhis is material for another question.
Perhaps my question does not make sense in regards to xml processing, but I tried to process the xml-code in this way and my question is: why did the negative lookahead not work as I expected?

Comment: If you post the regex with sample data to a regex debugger (for example, regex101.com), then someone might take a look.

Comment: The problem here is that lookahead/behind and negative lookahead/behind operate on what comes *immediately* before/after the preceding/following expression or text. Your second regex matches too much because the "(?!<\/category>)" part is effectively ignored (this due to the ".*?" which precedes it). I experimented with your data but I don't think there is a way to do what you want with a single regex. Rather I believe your best bet is to extract everything between each <category...></category> and then use a second regex to check if it contains a <parent>main_cat</parent>.

Comment: The problem here is that you are parsing XML with regex. Don't do that. Use an XML parser.

Comment: I want to know if it is possible to solve the problem using regular expressions... btw:I slightly changed the wording of the question.

Comment: It's not possible to do this with regular expressions. You come here asking for advice. "Use an XML parser" is the best advice you can get. Follow it.

Comment: "Use an XML parser": Parsing means to take the text file apart, write it in memory, change, and assamble it back ... This is a rather complicated and resource-intensive process. For example, if the XML file is about a gigabyte, it can be done only in parts (this does not simplify the matter). Optimized regex-query for just the task of replacing text can be much easier... btw: "It's not possible" without explanation == "I don't know how to do it"

Answer (score 0):

this works:

```
<tag>(?:[^<]|<(?!\/tag>))*content.*?<\/tag>
```

[found hier](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#explicit_greed)

[my example](https://regex101.com/r/ULZVO5/10)

Comment: @john-c if you are still interested